# Failed to initialise color list unarchiver

Tags: emacs, nskeyedunarchiver

Whenever I open an emacs file at the terminal, the following type of message occurs:

```
mm-Pro:~ mm$ emacs experiment.hs
2019-02-21 15:56:19.243 Emacs[2937:261832] Failed to initialize color     
list unarchiver: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "*** -
[NSKeyedUnarchiver_initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: 
non-keyed archive cannot be decoded by NSKeyedUnarchiver" UserInfo= 
{NSDebugDescription=*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:
throwLegacyExceptions:]: non-keyed archive cannot be decoded by NSKeyedUnarchiver}
```

What is the problem? Is this connected in any way to the fact that emacs keeps freezing on my computer?

Comment: See https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2018-09/msg00900.html for a fix

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71878108/m1-mac-errpr-emacs-error-failed-to-initialize-color-list-unarchiver-when-i-ca